# Generate interval from variable in Presto

Tags: sql, date, time, presto

In Presto SQL, unlike regular SQL, intervals must be created with inverted commas:

```
INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

rather than

```
INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I am trying to generate a set of dates as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/2388930, but am encountering an issue with

```
INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY
```

How might this be achieved? I tried

```
parse((a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) as varchar)
```

but this was not successful.

Answer (score 41):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but if the goal is to replicate the results described in the linked Stack Overflow question, [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range/2157776), here is an alternative method to generate a sequence of dates in Presto:

```
SELECT
    CAST(date_column AS DATE) date_column
FROM
    (VALUES
        (SEQUENCE(FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2010-01-20'), 
                  FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2010-01-24'), 
                  INTERVAL '1' DAY)
        )
    ) AS t1(date_array)
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column)
;
```

Output:

```
 date_column
-------------
 2010-01-20
 2010-01-21
 2010-01-22
 2010-01-23
 2010-01-24
```

You can also use other `INTERVAL` values besides `DAY` and different step sizes besides `'1'`.

*Adapted from this issue comment, https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2169#issuecomment-68521569.

Comment: `sequence` method only supports elements upto 10000. This error is returned when limit is exceeded: 
"result of sequence function must not have more than 10000 entries"

Answer (score 10):

I ended up using date_add:

```
date_add('day', -(a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)), date_trunc('day', now()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a simpler version of @wingr's answer the cross join and values parts seemed redundant:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM UNNEST(
        SEQUENCE(
            FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2010-01-20'),
            FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2010-01-24'),
            INTERVAL '1' DAY
        )
    )
 AS t1(date_array)
```